# How to make for loop only go to next line only when it finds a \n

Tags: python, for-loop

Title ^

So I have this code:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
```

#( site kind of glitched out I guess because of all these special characters so thats why it's not in the ``` )

file_contents = "           ^^                   @@@@@@@@\n      ^^       ^^            @@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n                           @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@              ^^\n                          @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\n~~~~ ~~ ~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~ ~~ &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& ~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~\n~         ~~   ~  ~       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~       ~~     ~~ ~\n  ~      ~~      ~~ ~~ ~~  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~  ~     ~~~    ~ ~~~  ~ ~~ \n  ~  ~~     ~         ~      ~~~~~~  ~~ ~~~       ~~ ~ ~~  ~~ ~ \n~  ~       ~ ~      ~           ~~ ~~~~~~  ~      ~~  ~             ~~\n      ~             ~        ~      ~      ~~   ~             ~\n"

#(this is supposed to be an ascii text art of a sunset)

```
for x in file_contents:
  if x == "~":
    print(Fore.RED + x)
  elif x == "&":
    print(Fore.CYAN + x)
  elif x == "@":
    print(Fore.YELLOW + x)
  elif x == "v" or x == "^":
    print(Fore.BLACK + x)
```

And while it does work as expected it prints every single character in a newline and if I put `,end = ''` it prints everything in the same line. So how could I make it so that it only goes to a newline if it finds a `\n`?

(Yes, I know I could technically manually but I'm lazy and that's going to take really long)

Comment: Set end to nothing again, check for \n the same way you check for the other characters, and print a newline if you see it.

Answer (score 1):

- Set `end=''` for all the print statements you already have
- Add

```
    elif x == "\n":
        print('')
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that before and it didn't work for some reason but now it does? I don't know but anyway, I just had to add ```elif x == " ": print(" ")``` to account for the spaces and now it all works!

Comment: I'm glad it worked!

Comment: `else: print(x)` is probably better

Answer (score 0):

You can use partial and path the print function:
(be cautious!)

```py
from functools import partial
print = partial(print, end='')
```

Comment: path -> monkeypatch. But why?